# Custom url redirect the page say You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page

Tags: php, wordpress

i have an error message whe i tring to set the page in custom url 
can anybody to tell that any action or hook to set the page or function. here is my code

```
    <a href='<?php echo admin_url("admin.php?page=wp_crm_asign&user_id={$user_id}"); ?>'>Asign to Consultant</a>

   add_action( 'admin_init', 'wp_crm_asign_admin_init' );


     function wp_crm_asign_admin_init() {

       if ($_GET['page'] == 'wp_crm_asign') {

        echo "hello";

        }
       }
```

Can Anybody to tell the right way to do this.
  thanks

Comment: why don't you call the function first, then set the href later?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create sub menu page with parent slug `null`, check here

`add_submenu_page(null,$page_title,$menu_title,8,'wp_crm_asign','wp_crm_asign_admin_init');`

Remove the `admin_init` hook and the function will automatically be called through this menu.

click [Here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_submenu_page/) to check the wordpress function.